# POSIX ERE regex using tail plugin within collectd

Tags: regex, posix, collectd

I am trying to match specific values in a file using the "tail" plugin for collectd.  This plugin only supports POSIX ERE syntax.  Sample file below:

```
capture.kernel_packets                     | Total                     | 25496291490
capture.kernel_drops                       | Total                     | 873229305
```

Attempt #1:

```
capture\.kernel_packets.*Total.*\|\s+(\d+)
```

I want to extract the value "25496291490" in the first capture group.

Attempt #2:

```
capture\.kernel_packets.*Total.*\|\s+(\d+)\1
```

It seems to only grab the full match.  The following works but is not supported by POSIX ERE:

```
capture\.kernel_packets.*Total.*\|\s+\K\S+
```

https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd.conf.5.shtml#plugin_tail
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_extended.html

What am I overlooking? Thanks!

Comment: Just remove `\1` from your first pattern.

Comment: @ctwheels I get the following error: `collectd[11093]: utils_match: match_apply: callback failed`,  presumably because it is expecting a number vs. the entire line. According to the documentation, the first subexpression has to match something that can be turned into a number by strtoll(3) or strtod(3)

Answer (score 1):

I think that your 1st attempt is close.

What I suspect you may be overlooking is the need to escape the string twice for use within collectd/tail. Let me explain.

First up, the collectd code is compiling the regex string you provide with the flags

```
REG_EXTENDED | REG_NEWLINE
```

But also, the string you provide in the tail.conf file in the Regex field is *not* the actual regex. It is a string suitable for use in the C language, so you have to be aware of the 2 separate levels of escaping.

1) the escaping required by the Extended Regex syntax e.g. if you want to use one of these

```
.[{}()\*+?|^$
```

then you need escape it with a `\`

So for example if you want to use the actual character '`*`', then the regex requires that you have '`\*`' so the compiler knows you means "asterisk" not "regex zero-or-more repeat".

2) But also, you need the escaping required by the C language.

So to produce the actual character '`|`' in the regex string, you need to escape it like this '`\|`'. And to provide that regex string in the tail.conf file as a C string, you need to escape it again '`\\|`'.

So you need this regex string :

```
capture\.kernel_packets.*Total.*\|\s+([0-9]+)
```

Which you would provide in your tail.conf with extra C escaping as :

```
capture\\.kernel_packets.*Total.*\\|\\s+([0-9]+)
```

The whole string is matched, and the number you want ends up in group 1, which gives collectd the number it needs for parsing.